# UPS battery connection

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

In a new UPS system, the batteries connection can be either:

One series connection of 100 cells.

Or a different battery with a different voltage that can give the same Ah by connecting three battery strings in parallel, where each battery string is made of 20 cells in series.

So, the total number of batteries will be 60.

Ignoring the cost, which option is more reliable?

Comment: is this a test question?

Comment: It depends how you define ‘reliable’?  Having the batteries as one series string means if one battery fails, then the system fails. Having a series/parallel scheme means one battery  from each string would have to fail. This is a simplistic way of looking at it. In reality determining  the reliability is somewhat more complex as it extends beyond the batteries themselves.

Comment: also note that "reliable" does not necessarily equate to less entropy.  With many backups, if a few fail, it can require more effort to detect and repair a failure which then again may cause more damage during that process.  More likely, financial decisions will cause a 3X backup to continue to be used after 2/3 have failed in order to get $ worth and grant someone simply looking at specs a false sense of security.

Comment: @Abel 
Sorry for my ignorance, when I translated entropy it gave me disorder (one of the meanings I think closest to your using) Am I right? you mean in simple words paying more in order to become more reliable has a drawback of more complex troubleshooting and more time-consuming maintenance and thus higher operational costs also. Did I get it right?

Comment: it can result in higher costs if not managed correctly.  Will your system be capable of reporting issues on each parallel chain?  the relationships between things are intertwined and people have a tendancy of only considering best-case scenarios.  ultimately to the laws of physics we pay for everything in increased disorder somewhere.  One of the reasons why keeping things simple prevails in the long run.